# Vegans: Besides supplements, what can substitute for Calcium?

Tags: veganism, vitamins-and-minerals, calcium

The RDA for Calcium is 900 mg for adults: what are some good calcium sources for vegans?

I already know of:

1. Tofu

Please exclude:

2. Any Calcium pills or supplements.
3. Milk and any dairy products.
4. Fortified Fruit Juices (because these are too saccharine and harm health).

Answer (score 16):

Calcium is readily available from a number of plant-based sources:

- [Tofu, processed with nigari](https://ndb.nal.usda.gov/ndb/foods/show/4886?man=&lfacet=&count=&max=&qlookup=&offset=&sort=&format=Abridged&reportfmt=other&rptfrm=&ndbno=&nutrient1=&nutrient2=&nutrient3=&subset=&totCount=&measureby=&Qv=1&Q9152=1&Qv=1&Q9152=0.2)* (100g) 282mg
- [Collard greens, cooked](https://ndb.nal.usda.gov/ndb/foods/show/2928?manu=&fgcd=&ds=) (1 cup)  268mg
- [Soybeans, cooked](https://ndb.nal.usda.gov/ndb/foods/show/3163?manu=&fgcd=&ds=) (1 cup) 261mg
- [Turnip greens](https://ndb.nal.usda.gov/ndb/foods/show/3244?fgcd=&manu=&lfacet=&format=&count=&max=50&offset=&sort=default&order=asc&qlookup=turnip%20greens&ds=&qt=&qp=&qa=&qn=&q=&ing=), cooked (1 cup)  197mg
- [Tempeh](https://ndb.nal.usda.gov/ndb/foods/show/4851?fgcd=&manu=&lfacet=&format=&count=&max=50&offset=&sort=default&order=asc&qlookup=tempeh&ds=&qt=&qp=&qa=&qn=&q=&ing=) (1 cup)  184mg
- [Mustard greens, cooked](https://ndb.nal.usda.gov/ndb/foods/show/3019?fgcd=&manu=&lfacet=&format=&count=&max=50&offset=&sort=default&order=asc&qlookup=mustard%20greens&ds=&qt=&qp=&qa=&qn=&q=&ing=) (1 cup) 165mg
- [Bok choy, cooked](https://ndb.nal.usda.gov/ndb/foods/show/2895?fgcd=&manu=&lfacet=&format=&count=&max=50&offset=&sort=default&order=asc&qlookup=bok%20choi&ds=&qt=&qp=&qa=&qn=&q=&ing=) (1 cup) 158mg
- [Navy beans, cooked](https://ndb.nal.usda.gov/ndb/foods/show/4777?manu=&fgcd=&ds=) (1 cup) 126mg
- [Almond butter](https://ndb.nal.usda.gov/ndb/foods/show/3707?man=&lfacet=&count=&max=&qlookup=&offset=&sort=&format=Abridged&reportfmt=other&rptfrm=&ndbno=&nutrient1=&nutrient2=&nutrient3=&subset=&totCount=&measureby=&Qv=1&Q6952=2&Q6953=1&Qv=1&Q6952=1&Q6953=1) (2 Tbsp) 111mg
- [Almonds, whole](https://ndb.nal.usda.gov/ndb/foods/show/3635?man=&lfacet=&count=&max=&qlookup=&offset=&sort=&format=Abridged&reportfmt=other&rptfrm=&ndbno=&nutrient1=&nutrient2=&nutrient3=&subset=&totCount=&measureby=&Qv=1&Q6809=.25&Q6810=1&Q6811=1&Q6812=1&Q6813=1&Q6814=1&Qv=1&Q6809=1&Q6810=1&Q6811=1&Q6812=1&Q6813=1&Q6814=1) (1/4 cup) 96mg
- [Kale, cooked](https://ndb.nal.usda.gov/ndb/foods/show/2984?manu=&fgcd=&ds=) (1 cup) 94mg
- [Blackstrap molasses](https://ndb.nal.usda.gov/ndb/foods/show/6293?man=&lfacet=&count=&max=&qlookup=&offset=&sort=&format=Abridged&reportfmt=other&rptfrm=&ndbno=&nutrient1=&nutrient2=&nutrient3=&subset=&totCount=&measureby=&Qv=1&Q11866=1&Q11867=2&Qv=1&Q11866=1&Q11867=1)  (2 Tbsp) 82mg
- [Okra, cooked](https://ndb.nal.usda.gov/ndb/foods/show/3027?fgcd=&manu=&lfacet=&format=&count=&max=50&offset=&sort=default&order=asc&qlookup=okra&ds=&qt=&qp=&qa=&qn=&q=&ing=) (1 cup) 65mg
- [Broccoli,cooked](https://ndb.nal.usda.gov/ndb/foods/show/2872?man=&lfacet=&count=&max=&qlookup=&offset=&sort=&format=Abridged&reportfmt=other&rptfrm=&ndbno=&nutrient1=&nutrient2=&nutrient3=&subset=&totCount=&measureby=&Qv=1&Q5401=1&Q5402=1&Q5403=1&Q5404=1&Q5405=1&Qv=1&Q5401=0.5&Q5402=1&Q5403=1&Q5404=1&Q5405=1) (1 cup) 62mg
- [Tahini](https://ndb.nal.usda.gov/ndb/foods/show/3740?man=&lfacet=&count=&max=50&qlookup=tahini&offset=&sort=default&format=Abridged&reportfmt=other&rptfrm=&ndbno=&nutrient1=&nutrient2=&nutrient3=&subset=&totCount=&measureby=&Qv=1&Q7019=2&Qv=1&Q7019=1) (2 Tbsp) 24mg

[Information taken from USDA Nutrient Database for Standard Reference, Release 28](https://ndb.nal.usda.gov/ndb/search/list)

Answer (score 10):

Dark leafy greens, nuts, and beans seem to be the best sources.

```
╔═════════════╦══════════════╦═════════════════╗
║     Food    ║ Portion size ║ Calcium/portion ║
╠═════════════╬══════════════╬═════════════════╣
║ tofu        ║   80g (raw)  ║      280mg      ║
╠═════════════╬══════════════╬═════════════════╣
║ kale        ║  120g (raw)  ║      180mg      ║
╠═════════════╬══════════════╬═════════════════╣
║ spinach     ║  120g (raw)  ║      119mg      ║
╠═════════════╬══════════════╬═════════════════╣
║ red beans   ║   80g (raw)  ║      115mg      ║
╠═════════════╬══════════════╬═════════════════╣
║ okra        ║  120g (raw)  ║       98mg      ║
╠═════════════╬══════════════╬═════════════════╣
║ chick peas  ║   80g (raw)  ║       84mg      ║
╠═════════════╬══════════════╬═════════════════╣
║ almond milk ║     200ml    ║       90mg      ║
╠═════════════╬══════════════╬═════════════════╣
║ almonds     ║      30g     ║       75mg      ║
╠═════════════╬══════════════╬═════════════════╣
║ broccoli    ║  120g (raw)  ║       66mg      ║
╠═════════════╬══════════════╬═════════════════╣
║ oranges     ║   1 medium   ║       60mg      ║
╚═════════════╩══════════════╩═════════════════╝
```

All values provided by the US Department of Agriculture.

EDIT: 200ml is the volume of a small glass. 30g is about an ounce.

Comment: Thanks for an answer in metric units (and not in cups).

Answer (score 5):

Dark leafy greens are a good source of calcium ([source](http://www.webmd.com/food-recipes/features/10-calcium-rich-foods)). Some good ones are kale (101 mg per serving), collard greens (84 mg per serving), and broccoli (70 mg per serving). You can also drink fortified non-dairy milks.

Answer (score 1):

The [Simple Happy Kitchen](https://www.simplehappykitchen.com/) provides this fun infographic about plant-based calcium sources (along with similar graphics for [protein and iron](https://www.simplehappykitchen.com/protein-calcium-iron/)). The top few fall into several groups:

- Fortified foods: soy milk, tofu
- Legumes: soybeans, white beans, edamame, chickpeas, adzuki beans
- Spinach
- Seeds: tahini, chia
- Other greens: broccoli, okra, snap peas

[image]